# Simulate keytool password keyboard input in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, expect, keystore, keytool

I have like 100 keystore e.g. "store15.jks" files, and a single X.509 certificate "mycert.pem". I need to find out in which "store*.jks", "mycert.pem" is imported in. What I am trying to do is to make a script to iterate 100 times and do command

```
keytool -list -keystore store*.jks
```

I initially came up with simple script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for((i=1;i<100;i++))
do
cert="mycert.pem"
str="store"$i".jks"
OUTPUT="$(keytool -list -keystore $str)"
echo $OUTPUT
done
```

Alas, at the first iteration already, I am prompted for keystore password, like

```
Enter keystore password:   //3 or 4 spaces after colon
```

That means I'd have to enter password for every single iteration, and there must be a (much) better way to do this, i.e. a way to simulate keyboard input when password is prompted. Browsing through the Stack Overflow I found some examples using certain "Expect" scripting, but they were either rudimentary or I just couldn't manage to get it right, so I failed at combining /bash and /expect. Must say I find it a bit strange that there is no /bash technique for task that might see pretty common. I would appreciate any help, preferring example scripts. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use the `-storepass` option of `keytool` (which allows to specify the password on the command line)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the `-storepass` option which allows you to pass the password on the command line.  If for some reason that does not work for you (maybe you have an earlier version), here is an `expect` script that works for me:

```
expect -c "spawn /usr/bin/keytool -list; expect \"assword:\" { exp_send \"the_password\r\"}; expect EOF {exit}"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks alot to both of you guys, -storepass worked like a charm! You made me very happy :)

I'll now post my updated script that solved the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

for((i=1;i<100;i++))
do
str="store"$i".jks"
sha="5A:6B:18"
OUTPUT="$(keytool -list -keystore $str -storepass mypass | grep $sha )"
echo $i
echo $OUTPUT
done
```

The answer to the original problem is store74.jks. Hope this helps someone someday.

Answer (score 0):

For viewing public keys, now password is needed; if you can output a simple "ENTER" keystroke, that should suffice, too.
E.g.

```
echo "" |keytool -list -keystore key.jks
```